# Is it possible to remove add tab ( + )' for a profile.?

Tags: profile, tab, ui

[image]

I need to remove this add tab button.Is it possible?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling you're asking the wrong question. Why do you need to remove the "All Tabs" tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to remove as this is a standard platform feature.  You should remove the tabs you don't want to display to the profile.